# Is there any alternative way to access JavaScript globals that have been shadowed or redefined?

Tags: javascript

For some unknown reason the name `URL` in my event handler points to a string value with the current URL of the browser instead of the constructor for an URL object. Trying to call it results in the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: URL is not a constructor
```

The string URL does not appear anywhere in the loaded document which leads me to believe that it is not redefined anywhere in my program. I have not been able to find anything other that would explain why this phenomena occurs.

So my question for a workaround is: Is it possible to access these global constructors in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, through the name `window`, as long as it too hasn't been shadowed or redefined:

```
let a = new window.URL(location);
```

Comment: That only works in the browser and Deno. Many engines don't have a `window` object, e.g. Node.js and Rhino

Comment: Did you answered yourself or is it precision about your question ?

Comment: The above answers my question, yes.